# How do I detect a real trailer?

Tags: trailers

Nowadays, when a trailer of an expected film comes out, fans usually make <strike>hundreds</strike> thousands of fake trailers. And most of the times on YouTube they call it like it is the real trailer. And there are also situations when they make fake trailers from the previous film before the real trailer comes out and it may seem that the real trailer is already out. How to avoid that?

Comment: Can you give an example of a fake trailer?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=njF9p2SWi64. I'm can't be sure; but I think when this video first was published (or one very similar for the same movie), the description did not make it clear that it was "fake".

Comment: This too is Fan Made (but it says in the title) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eNykS4VlnwE

Comment: How can you be confused by that Lion King trailer? Uploaded on some doofus's channel, uses a badly sounding voice-over from another movie, consists of bland stock footage and then has amateurish graphics.

Comment: Stop looking at user generated content websites for trailers to begin with. Every film will have a dedicated website these days, or a dedicated page on the production studio's website.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Given the ease of use of modern editing software and the availability of high-quality source files, "fake" trailers can look as good or better than "real" trailers. One sign of a "fake" trailer is when the action and cuts don't match the beats of the trailer's soundtrack, though a good editor will avoid that.

One solution is to go to the film studio's own channel to see if the trailer is posted there. For example, there are a number of channels that repost Marvel Cinematic Universe trailers, remix them, or edit them together in a series to make it look like a longer clip, but the Marvel Entertainment channel at [MARVEL](https://www.youtube.com/user/MARVEL) should always have the real trailer for any upcoming MCU film.

All of the major studios have their own channels; I subscribe to most of them specifically to avoid the issue you're talking about.

Another approach is to manage what channels YouTube uses to recommend videos to you. If you notice you're getting recommendations from sub-par channels instead of the actual sources, you can click the three dots just below the thumbnail to the right and select the "Not Interested" option.

[image: Screengrab from YouTube showing the three-dot menu selected]

When you get the response "VIDEO REMOVED," choose the "Tell us why" option and choose the "I'm not interested" in this channel option.

[image: Screengrab showing Tell Us Why option]

[image: Screengrab showing I'm not interested option]

After you do this enough times you won't be getting the most common undesired recommendations.

(Note, I'm a fan of Screen Junkies, so I'm just showing this for illustrative purposes.)

Another approach (recommended by Ankit Sharma in the comments) is to check to see whether the channel posting the video is verified by YouTube as "belong[ing] to an established creator or is the official channel of a brand, business, or organization," which is indicated by a [verification checkmark](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/3046484?hl=en):

[image: Screen grab with verification checkmark]

Note that this channel lacks the checkmark:
[image: Screen grab without verification checkmark]

This isn't foolproof, since many channels that repost trailers are verified, but you may see material posted by someone with a lookalike name such as "Marvel Movies" that doesn't have the check.

Comment: It also helps to follow channels of established film news outlets such as Deadline, Entertainment Weekly, Variety, Vanity Fair, or Cinema Blend, etc, because they will only release trailers that are legit.  But obviously going straight to the Studio's source is probably the best way.

Comment: There is a drawback in that you will also get inundated with trailers and other promos from that studio for films you may not care for.

Comment: Another pont here, You have no way of identifying Official fake trailers (like the one with Avengers Infinity War), because it **is** official trailer, while it has no connection to actual movie.

Comment: Also, even though this usually only happens with TV series, sometimes the first Official Teaser Trailer only consist of previous film footage (case and point the first Official (HBO Released) Game of Thrones Season 8 Trailer).

Answer (score 4):

Since people today do ANYTHING to get views, like using attractive titles and highly custom cover photos for their video, I'd suggest that please **refer the video-poster's name** which always flashes under the videos title.

A very few people write '(Fan-made)' in their video titles but please note that many don't, as it's not a compulsion imposed by Youtube and they all work around them **views**.

As for my answer,I would never open any MCU-related video unless it is posted by Marvel or any connected(trusted) partner.